# How could we change the app name in Wagtail after creation?

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, wagtail

Because of some mistakes in naming the apps during their creation with Wagtail and working on their content for some days, It's important to know how we could change their name after creation with Wagtail.

I'm trying to do it with Django's methods for creating and changing the app name. But they didn't work perfectly (I got error).

For example, as an exercise, I decided to change the "breads" app name in bakerydemo to "services". I did the following steps:

1. I changed the app directory name from "breads" to "services"
2. I changed INSTALLED_APPS in myapp/myapp/settings/base.py from "myapp.breads" to "myapp.services"
3. Then I run makemigrations and got the error:
   File "myapp\myapp\base\wagtail_hooks.py", line 9, in  from myapp.breads.models import BreadIngredient, BreadType, Country ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp. breads'

I fixed it with the new app name.

4. Then I run makemigrations and got the error:
   File " myapp\myapp \search\views.py", line 8, in  from myapp.breads.models import BreadPage
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp.breads'

I fixed it with the new app name.

5. Then I run makemigrations and got the error:
   File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\wagtail\utils\registry.py", line 83, in foreign_key_lookup for model in target_model.mro():
   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mro'

I fixed it by changing the app name in myapp\myapp\models.py

6. Then I run makemigrations and got the error:
   File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 60, in raise_error
   raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
   django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration services.0004_use_json_field_for_body_streamfield dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('breads', '0003_auto_20170329_0055')

I have not been able to fix this error yet. Then I asked that general question to find a ***general*** and ***straight forward*** solution for other apps like the blog or ….

Answer (score 1):

Without details of what "didn't work perfectly" there isn't any way for us to help you do it correctly.

I will say that renaming apps and models after they are already in use is a bit of a tricky process - in Django and in Wagtail. So, do you really need to rename them? or would setting the verbose name fields to your preferred name be sufficient?

```
   class WorkingPaperPage(Page):
       ... field info here....

       class Meta:
            verbose_name = 'Draft Paper'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Draft Papers'
```

Comment: Anything is ok. I like to change an app name for example "blog to "news" ... How can I do this?

Comment: https://realpython.com/move-django-model/ shows how to move a model between apps. So for your 'rename app', I would choose one of those methods, create a new "news" app, and move your models and their data into the new app. 

But I will repeat, do you need to rename the app? What is driving your desire to rename the app after it is already in use?

Comment: Yes, as I said before, I need to rename the app name sometimes after creation. because it may be a wrong word or inconvenient name in some situations.

Answer (score 1):

So you have discovered why renaming apps is difficult - because the model names and even the app name are used for references from other places.

Do you need to keep existing data from the current app? If not, start by removing the current app from the database. I can't give you exact steps but it should be something like 1) [migrate the app to 'zero'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/migrations/#reversing-migrations) to drop all the tables 2) make Django forget ALL about those models by running [remove_stale_contenttypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#django-contrib-contenttypes). Hopefully that gives you bare database. So you can rename your app, and all the views and other models that might be referring to it.

If you need to keep existing data, I would do something like what is detailed in https://realpython.com/move-django-model/#the-long-way-copy-the-data-to-a-new-django-model but for all of the models in your app. Once the old data is in the new tables, then you can do as outlined above to remove the old app.

As you see this is a TON of work and involves a bunch of steps that could destroy your database. Please be sure you have good backups of the production database and have practiced this change end-to-end a couple of times in a test environment before touching the production database.

Comment: Yes, I need to keep existing data, as I said before we must change the app name after creation, this means that may we work on it for days or weeks and it has some child page and data. Don't worry, I have a backup of any solution. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Hi, I studied the "How to Move a Django Model to Another App" tutorials based on your recommendation. It suggests 3 methods: 1. Copy data 2. Change Table 3. Rename table. As you know in any case in these methods the internal model and data inside two apps are different, while in our case the model is the same and only some naming issues are different based on the app's new name. I like to know your Idea in this situation and what is your suggestion about the methods. which one is better in this case?

Comment: The article summarizes the pros and cons of each option - https://realpython.com/move-django-model/#guidelines-choose-the-best-approach. I would say either option 2 or 3 would be fine. The one time I have had to do this in Wagtail (to move my custom Document model), I used option 3: Rename Table.

Comment: I tried to do the third method. But I think there is some mistake in performing the sequence of its steps. For example, in its sequence, the app doesn't produce the file: "0003_delete_product.py" in the "product/migration" directory. Also the file "0002_alter_sale_product.py" is not in the "sale/migration directory". After some trial on the rearrangement of the sequence for performing the migration, It didn't produce the file "sale/migrations/0002_auto_20200110_1304.py". I couldn't solve it. what is the problem?